# Combining User and UserProfile in the admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have been reading up on Django's separation of Users and Profiles, and I have decided to go with a model called UserProfile that is located in an Accounts app as my Profile.  The problem is, now I have two separate areas of the admin, one for modifying the User, and one for modifying the User Profile.  Is it possible to view the two models as one in the admin, so if you add or modify a user you see all of the fields for both User and Profile in the same view?    It also kinda goes without saying that adding a deleting a user should add or delete a profile with it, and it shouldn't be possible to add or delete a profile without the user.

I've seen bits and pieces of how to make this work (for example, something that adds a profile when you add a user), but not as a whole.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by using [inline admin models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

before writing your custom `User` admin you have to unregister the already registered `User` admin

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
```

define the Inline `UserProfile`

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile
```

and use the inline in the `User` admin

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: When I do this I get several "profile" forms underneath each user, and I can't save data into it; that causes '"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"'. Is this because South screwed up or dit things change in the past year? Looking for some directions here, tnx.