# Why do my Django inlines show multiple forms for single model?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm attempting to combine the admin form for the User and my UserProfile model. I found out how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605465/combining-user-and-userprofile-in-the-admin/3606090#comment-9015907), which works. I have this now:

```
#DJANGOPROJECT/generic/admin.py
class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]

admin.site.unregister(admin.models.User)
admin.site.register(admin.models.User, UserAdmin)
```

However, the form generated in the admin contains five instances of the user profile form, instead of one. I don't understand why this is?

Comment: No many more, I thought about that but no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

> **InlineModelAdmin.extra** This controls the number of extra forms the
>   formset will display in addition to the initial forms. See the
>   formsets documentation for more information.
>
> New in Django 1.2: Please, see the release notes For users with
>   JavaScript-enabled browsers, an "Add another" link is provided to
>   enable any number of additional inlines to be added in addition to
>   those provided as a result of the extra argument.
>
> The dynamic link will not appear if the number of currently displayed
>   forms exceeds max_num, or if the user does not have JavaScript
>   enabled.
>
> **InlineModelAdmin.max_num** This controls the maximum number of forms
>   to show in the inline. This doesn't directly correlate to the number
>   of objects, but can if the value is small enough. See Limiting the
>   number of editable objects for more information.

Try to set max_num to 1

Comment: I've set it to 0, and extra as wel, which reduces the number of forms to one. It's strange. Although I have superuser rights I can only change my own profile from the admin, and when I do so an additional form appears...